# Starting with audio in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I recently started doing some development in the Windows Phone 8 OS I'm pretty new on this. I was doing some searching about the fact to create an app who play any audio for some specific events/actions.

I was reading the **Windows Phone API reference** from **Windows Phone Dev Center** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Win32andCOMAPIforWindowsPhone

But it seems a little confusing to me at first glance and I have the doubt of which one of the following should I use to accomplish my task.

1. The .Net API for Windows Phone
2. Win 32 and COM API
3. ... or the Windows Phone Runtime API

Any help would be very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're trying to do. If you're writing a native application or are interested in cross-compatability with Windows 8 then XAudio2 or the WinRT APIs are definitely the way to go. If you just want to play some infrequent sounds (say, when you pop up a warning dialog) from within a XAML app then I have seen a number of approaches, teh easiest of which is probably just having a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your XAML that you use to play the audio.

Comment: Well, the thing I'm trying to do is to create an app where you can specify the audio you would like to play when for example a notification mail comes

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API on Windows Phone that allows you to specify system sounds from an app.